# can we delete the target folder which is generating in executable jar in maven2

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml, multi-module

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>auto-clean</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${project.build.Directory}</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.jar</include>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
           </filesets>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

i am using this plugin to delete the target folder which is coming in executable jar of module after build , which shouldn't came.

is there any other way to get rid of this type of things during build.By normal way it shouldn't came.

in the pom i have added so many resources from so many different module.

Comment: Why have you bound clean plugin to install phase? does not really make sense? Furthermore why are you using such an old version of clean plugin?

Comment: okay then if i will change the version to 3.0.0 and phase to initialise then it will work , you think ??

Comment: after trying these things no file getting created in the executable jar where i want only the target folder in executable jar to deleate.

Comment: If you do by default a `mvn clean package` everything should work. If you need such configuration there is something wrong in your build...If you really using Maven 2 you shouldn't use version 3.0.0 of Maven-Clean-plugin (better 2.6 is the last version which supports Maven 2).

Comment: i have tried with 2.6 but still it didn't delete the target.

Comment: What does it mean: `still it didn't delete the target` ? Do you get an error message? Are you working on Windows? Furthermore a full pom would help to identify the probelm.